# Random sample within a certain range in a list (array) | Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, random, range

I have a list with many characters in it like such:

```
list = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q',
        'r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9',
        '0'," ",'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P',
        'Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
```

I want the program to randomly pick 8 characters within the first 26 (lowercase letters) items in my list. I will not delete or separate the other items in this array as I need them later for a similar thing.

I am somewhat new to programming and I prefer a simple solution, although I am not stopping you from putting something more complex out there for others to see.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Usually, you don't need a list for this kind of sequence of 1-character strings; just use a single string `list = 'abc...xyz1234567890 ABC...XYZ'`

Comment: as a side note, if your list is similar to that have you seen python's string module? Specifically string.ascii_letters and string.digits?

Comment: after importing string, mylist = list(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits + " " + string.ascii_uppercase) will give you almost exactly what you have (with the position of 0 changed), or remove the list() to get what @chepner suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can slice the array, to sample it.

```
random.sample(seq[:26], k=8)
```

Answer (score 1):

Firsty you need the [random module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html):

```
import random
```

Then I would use this solution:

```
your_list = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q',
        'r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9',
        '0'," ",'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P',
        'Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']

first_26_characters = your_list[0:26] # get items from 0 to 26 in new list
random.shuffle(first_26_characters) # shuffle new list
random_8_characters = first_26_characters[0:8] # get first 8 characters because after shuffle they are random
```

I hope this helps!